# How do you get raw TCP packet in C#?

Tags: c#, networking, .net-4.0, tcp

I want to received raw TCP packet and then send it back with same workload.

It should look something like this:

```
void OnPacketReceived(TcpPacket p)
{
    byte [] body = p.GetBody();
}
```

NOTE : I need the TCP packet and not the Ethernet frame.

Comment: I could be 100% wrong, but I'm not sure if this is possible to do with managed code. As far as I know the socket library in C# uses streams exclusively, thus abstracting away packet boundaries.

Comment: well lets see if someone could have cracked this.

Comment: Have you looked at http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/ It's a .net wrapper around WinPcap.

Comment: yes. but this is why i asked specifically tcp not ethernet. I dont want to write my own NDIS and I dont want a full-blown sniffer as I want lowest latency possible. pcap is way too slow in this case.

Comment: you must to extract tcp packet informations from ethernet's ip frame.

Comment: what you want to do? please describe more about your whim , if you need a tcp server to handle tcp packets and response to it, you need some experiences in win32,c++,mfc & com components. but another simple solution are exists: win32 tun/tap

Comment: I want to minimize number of 'logical' layouts inside socket wrapper. and if this is a whim for you I think you shouldnt be answering this question. ta

Comment: The question sounds like you're trying to implement TCP echo?  What would be wrong with a plain TCP socket and just sending the payload right back at the other endpoint?

Comment: What have you investigated yourself?

Comment: Also, you realize that TCP handling is often done in hardware anyway?  Using the built-in .NET TCP implementation is likely to be the fastest thing you can do, since it's just a wrapper around the native win32 libraries in the first place.  I don't understand what could possibly be so latency sensitive that it's ok to use C# but not ok to use the built-in TCP socket capabilities.  Are you trying to optimize clear down to the CPU cycle?  If that's the case, don't do this in C#.

Comment: this is echo. I will compare raw and logical sockets anyway. and publish the results. But i expect raw to be few ns faster (difficult to measure on Windows but I will try)... I know that C++ on RH would be faster but that is outside of the scope of this project

Comment: @Default although this looks simple is needed a careful consideration. I am going to implement both - raw and logical socket and see the difference. in about 2 week time as the server in questions is in transit yet.

Comment: Echo is also built in to windows, if all you need is echo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you implement the socket as a raw socket, you have access to the whole packet (and in fact must handle everything about the packet yourself).

Use SocketType.Raw and ProtocolType.Raw when creating the socket.

Just be aware that you're going to have to handle the details of TCP if you implement your socket this way.

For reference, here is the MSDN documentation about the Socket class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx

Comment: +1: I've used that method to check if a TCP packet's header has a checksum or not (since it's not mandatory).

Comment: @AllonGuralnek could you share the code please? or at least to outline what has to be done to achieve that?

Comment: @dodexahedron - are you 100% positive that if I connect raw socket I get access to the TCP packet straight? (this is actually the question). if you are sure could you please confirm that and I mark it as the answe. thank you.

Comment: Yes.  Note that opening a socket this way in .NET requires administrator permissions (must run application as administrator, in Vista+) or you will get an exception.  You will have access to the entire packet as the byte array, when using a raw socket, vs just the payload, when using a TCP socket.

Comment: Also realize that, as I said, you have to implement TCP in order for this to work.  The handshake won't even be handled for you, any more.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pcapDotNet library.

https://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/

Comment: Useful library, Thanks for suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Packet sniffer where you can put filters of your choice and on the basis of that can respond also.

.Net wrapper around WinPcap can prove to be helpful for you.