# How can i get CRC from received data by TCP?

Tags: c#, tcp, ethernet

I need to send Ethernet packets from one device to another by Ethernet protocol. After some research i decide to use TCP\IP protocol. I created TCP server and TCP client that communicating with each other. I used TcpClient and TcpListener classes for that. It works fine, but i have some questions:

1. I need to check CRC from received message and compare it with manually calculated on the listener side somehow. How can i do this? How can i get this CRC from received message? All i got it's an exact message that i send from client.
2. How in common to see my message in this packet format? All that i see at the Listener side it's "Data" field, but i wanna see "raw" with headers, CRC(FCS) etc,
   [like at that picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUSQ2.png)

Comment: "I need to send Ethernet packets  from one device to another" and "i decide to use TCP\IP" doesn't add up. The protocols are on different layers. (And an Ethernet PDU is better referred to as a frame, not a packet.)

Comment: you may use a packet analyzer tool, for example tcpdump or Wireshark

Comment: @stickybit   Sorry, i'm still novice at that. Actually that's true, i totally confused with this layers. Can you recommend something to read for clarifying that? Not like book, but something like fast reading.
And what can you recommend me in that situation? How can i send this ethernet frames in this raw form and read them aswell?

Comment: @mangusta thank you! I will try search for it. But that's mean that i couldn't get CRC at TCP/IP protocol by native .NET tools?

Comment: I think that's all embedded within TCP Client and not visible. It uses this to ensure that the data is received properly (without errors). If you are concerned about security (such as someone intercepting and changing the data) more than error checking you would need to send your own checksum along with the transmitted data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Svemir, you can check [SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034870/how-do-you-get-raw-tcp-packet-in-c) about raw communication using Sockets in C#.

[Here is a good SuperUser explanation of the various layers](https://superuser.com/questions/206431/ethernet-vs-tcp-vs-ip/206437). If you go with the raw method of the Sockets, then you are in for some hard times

> you're going to have to handle the details of TCP if you implement your socket this way.

From Microsoft documentation on SocketType.Raw

> Supports access to the underlying transport protocol. Using Raw, you can communicate using protocols like Internet Control Message Protocol (ProtocolType.Icmp) and Internet Group Management Protocol (ProtocolType.Igmp). Your application must provide a complete IP header when sending. Received datagrams return with the IP header and options intact

From Microsoft documentation on SocketType.Stream

> Supports reliable, two-way, connection-based byte streams without the duplication of data and without preservation of boundaries. A Socket of this type communicates with a single peer and requires a remote host connection before communication can begin. Stream uses the Transmission Control Protocol (ProtocolType.Tcp) and the AddressFamily.InterNetwork address family.

Which basically means that everything is handled for you and that you can only have access to what the SuperUser link refers to as the letter contents.

Comment: Thank you very much, Athanasios! Your answer is very helpful, and now i know about this protocols much more and know how it's works. But i think, for now, i will choose the path that @TroyMac1ure has advised. Cause this Raw sockets seems very hard for me yet. But for future, i know how to deal with that. Thank you!